# Android JPEG write EXIF data

Tags: android, camera, jpeg, exif

When camera application captures a photo, it saves **Date Taken** data in the captured image. As shown in below screen.

[image]

I have created custom camera in Android. I want to write the same field **Date Taken** data on a JPEG file, I used `ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME` field to achieve this. But the API is not able to write this field. See the below image. Please tell me what can be the issue?

[image]

I used below code to achieve this:

```
ExifInterface mObjExifInterface = new ExifInterface(amsFCapturePhoto);
mObjExifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, getDateTimeByFormat(
                        DATE_FORMAT_YEAR_MONTH_DATE_SHORT_TIME));
mObjExifInterface.saveAttributes();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the code seems clear, debug the value returned by `getDateTimeByFormat(                       DATE_FORMAT_YEAR_MONTH_DATE_SHORT_TIME)`

Comment: @anil: Its giving **2015-06-01 11:19:05**. Are you pointing, this issue could be of date format!!

Comment: possibly [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004462/cant-set-date-taken-datetime-tag-using-the-exifinterface-in-android)

Comment: @bilal: I have already gone through that possible duplicate. But as it did not solve my issue thats why I posted this question.

Comment: Did you check for an error returned by the setAttribute call?