# EXIFTool JSON to EXIF batch processing

Tags: java, json, batch-file, exif, exiftool

I have >400 JPG files and a JSON file for each which contains the image tags, description and title. I've found this command

```
exiftool -json=picture.json picture.jpg
```

But I don't want to run this for each and every file.
How can I run this command for the folder containing the JPGs and JSONs or is there another way I can batch process these?
Each JSON file has the same name as it's JPG counterpart so it's easy to identify which files match up to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JPGs and JSONs have the same filename, but different extesion(e.g. picture001.jpg has an associated picture001.json,etc.), a batch for loop might work.
Assuming you've already `cd`-ed into the folder and the files aren't nested in folders, something like this should work

```
( for jpg in *.jpg; do exiftool -json=${jpg/\.jpg/.json} $jpg; done )
```

Note that this isn't tested. I recommend making a copy of your folder and testing there beforehand to make sure you don't irreversibly damage them.

I've also noticed you're using the java tag. I had to work with EXIF data in Java a while back ([on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004462/cant-set-date-taken-datetime-tag-using-the-exifinterface-in-android/17245640#17245640) then) and I used the [JHeader library](http://jheader.sourceforge.net/). If you want to roll your own little java command line tool, you should be able to use Java's IO classes to traverse your directory and files and the JHeader library to modify the EXIF data.

Comment: Thanks!

I tried this but ran into an error, there isn't enough space in this textbox for me to copypaste it but [here's a screenshot of what I did and what happened.](http://i.imgur.com/UZl681a.png)

Comment: You didn't mention windows. My solution is in bash, you can run on unix systems.  On Windows you'll need something like [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/). Note that you run the script as it is, without exiftool.exe in front. At the moment I won't be able to do a DOS/batch version, but the same principles apply. The syntax will be different

Comment: Ah OK, sorry I forgot to say I was on Windows! Thank you, I'll download cygwin, I believe I've used that before.

Comment: cygwin wasn't working out for me so I fired up an Ubuntu VM, installed exiftool and ran your command but it's throwing back these three lines for each file

Line 1: "No SourceFile entries in 'imagename.json'"
Line 2: "No SourceFile 'imagename.jpg' in imported JSON database"
Line 3: "(absolute path: '/media/FlickrPics/imagename.jpg')"

Comment: Sounds like the paths aren't quick right. I did a quick dummy test: added a bunch of json and jpg files```ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 georgeprofenza  staff  0 10 Aug 14:58 pic001.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 georgeprofenza  staff  0 10 Aug 14:58 pic001.json
-rw-r--r--  1 georgeprofenza  staff  0 10 Aug 14:59 pic002.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 georgeprofenza  staff  0 10 Aug 14:58 pic002.json
-rw-r--r--  1 georgeprofenza  staff  0 10 Aug 14:59 pic003.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 georgeprofenza  staff  0 10 Aug 14:59 pic003.json``` then ran a slightly modified version of the script which only prints data to the prompt...

Comment: ...but doesn't call exiftool, just to test the paths: ```( for jpg in *.jpg; do echo ${jpg/\.jpg/.json} $jpg; done )``` and it prints the expected output: ```pic001.json pic001.jpg
pic002.json pic002.jpg
pic003.json pic003.jpg```. Did you call  ```cd /media/FlickrPics/```before running the for loop above ?

Comment: Yep I ran cd first. I just ran your test command, calling echo instead of exiftool, and it produced the expected result (same as yours). I then tried the command calling exiftool once more and again it did not work. Could it be something to do with the contents of the JSON files? That's all I can think of now. The content of each JSON is as follows: `{"Tags":"seperate, image, tags, here","Description":"Image description here","Title":"Image Title Here"}`

Comment: I assumed your configurations were already working since your question is about batch processing and not about using the tool itself. Have you tested with a single image and json file first ? I haven't used exiftool before. is [this](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) it ?

Comment: Yeah that's it. Reading up on this error, turns out there should be a line in the JSON file like so `"SourceFile": "sourcefilename.jpg",` I'm not sure why that wasn't already there. Completely different question but have you any idea of a way I could grab each JSON (or JPG) files' name and put it into each JSON file? I can easily add `"SourceFile": ".jpg",` to every file within seconds, but it's the adding each different name to each different file that would take a long time to do manually. Hope this makes sense...

Comment: This should be a different question. I haven't played with editing file contents in a look that much. Assuming the json contents are the same, a hacky solution is to simply edit 1 file and pass the same json file to every jpg. It sounds more logical that you would have individual configurations per jpg though.

Comment: No each JSON has seperate tags, descriptions and titles for it's JPG counterpart. I'll make a seperate question. Thank you so very much for all your help!